# hide time_out, _shards, max_score and other default fields from output

Tags: json, api, elasticsearch

When i perform any search query in elastic search i get output with these fields added automatically,

```
{
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 17,
        "successful": 17,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 122,
        "max_score": 10.268,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "imdb",
                "_type": "txt",
                "_id": "f4c8929735ad",
                "_score": 11.775636,
```

my desired fields are everything under `_source`

```
               "_source": {
                       "actor_name": {
                          "attribute": "value2"
                     },
                      "age_data":{
                        "perm": 29
                    }
                }
```

How can I filter out everything from displaying at the output except `_source` in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1):

You could use filter path functionality to filter only what you want to have. Something like this should help:

```
host:port/_search?pretty&filter_path=hits.hits._source
```

In this case you would have response like this:

```
{
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      {
        "_source": {
          "type": "type",
          "date": "2018-05-10T16:54:54.162Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source": {
          "type": "type",
          "date": "2018-05-14T10:39:15.903Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

More information on filter path - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering